# Login automatically to get a scraped file on Rails app with Mechanize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, screen-scraping, mechanize-ruby

To login then to download a PDF file, I have a code that works perfectly fine on ruby when I Debug. Problem is, when I try to use this code on a Rails app with an instance variable, I can't download the file, guess that it's a cookie issue but I didn't achieve to resolve it

here the code that works on Ruby (i can download the PDF file, so the login is a success):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new

agent.pluggable_parser.pdf = Mechanize::FileSaver

page = agent.get("http://elwatan.com/sso/inscription/inscription_payant.php")

# login to the site
form = page.form_with(:id => 'form-login-page')
form.login = "my_login"
form.password = "my_password"
page = form.submit

#get the PDF link    
agent.get("http://elwatan.com/").parser.xpath('//div[2]/div/p/a/@href|/img').each do       |link|
agent.get link['href']
end
```

And below my attempt on Ruby On Rails 3, didn't work (I can scrape the link, but not downloading the file because I am getting redirected to the login page:

**Controller.rb**

```
@agent = Mechanize.new
@agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
@page = @agent.get("http://elwatan.com/sso/inscription/inscription_payant.php")

# login
form = @page.form_with(:id => 'form-login-page')
form.login = "my_login"
form.password = "my_password"
@page = form.submit

# get the PDF link
@watan = {}
@agent.get("http://elwatan.com/").parser.xpath('//div[2]/div/p/a/@href|/img').each do     |link|
@watan[link.text.strip] = @agent.get link['href']
end
```

**View.rb**

```
<% if @watan %>
<% @watan.each do |key, value| %>
<a href="http://www.elwatan.com<%= "#{key}" %>" target='_blank'>download my file</a>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You login in your server, fetch the links, and then send those links to the browser. The browser is in a totally different session so this can never work. This should not be a surprise. Instead you should make it a link back to your server, who can then fetch the document and send it to your browser.

Comment: thank you for your answer. as I am a begginer on ruby, any hint about how to login in my server and send the link to the browser ? many thanks

Comment: Obviously I am speaking chinese, I will try to answer you in full later. The sentence "login in my server and send the links" referred to what you were already doing correctly. But the browser, your user, does not share the session, so presenting her a full link from a logged in user will always fail.

Comment: Sorry, I admit that I responded hurriedly; in fact, it's the "make it a link back to your server" that I wanted to ask for help. thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be a long post.

First off, you should place your scraping code in a libary, so create the file `lib/watan_scraper.rb` and fill it with

```
module WatanScraper

  def self.get_all_pdfs
    agent = get_agent
    # get the PDF link

    watan = []
    agent.get("http://elwatan.com/").parser.xpath('//div[2]/div/p/a/@href|/img').each do     |link|
      watan << link.text.strip
    end
    watan
  end


  def self.get_single_pdf(link_text)
    agent = get_agent
    # get the PDF link

    found_link= nil
    agent.get("http://elwatan.com/").parser.xpath('//div[2]/div/p/a/@href|/img').each do     |link|
      if link.text.strip = link_text 
        found_link = link['href']
      end 
    end

    pdf = 
    if found_link
      # fetch pdf
      agent.get(found_link)
    end
  end


  private

  def get_agent
    agent = Mechanize.new
    agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
    page = agent.get("http://elwatan.com/sso/inscription/inscription_payant.php")

    # login
    form = page.form_with(:id => 'form-login-page')
    form.login = "my_login"
    form.password = "my_password"
    form.submit

    agent
  end

end
```

Ok, and now you can write in your controller

```
class PdfsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @watan = WatanScraper.get_all_pdfs
  end

  def show
    pdf_name = params[:id]
    @pdf = WatanScraper.get_pdf(pdf_name)
    send_data @pdf, :filename => "#{padf_name}.pdf"
  end
end
```

Your view should be in file `views/pdfs/index.html.haml` (let's use [haml](http://haml.info)

```
- @watan.each do |link_text| 
  = link_to "Download #{link_text}", pdf_path(link_text)
```

Your routes should be as follows (`config/routes.rb`)

```
resources :pdfs, only: [:index, :show]
```

This code is of course untested, but this at least is nicely structured and will fetch the pdf in the right session (using mechanize) and then sends it back to the browser.

Comment: Thank you, really helped me; I followed the instruction and succeeded to manage some issues, but still stumbling on the last step: the page "http://localhost:3000/pdfs" gives me the wished link, but gets me to a Routing Error (=> No route matches [GET] "/pdfs/pdf/telecharger.php%3Fdir=JOURNAL&file=20140701.pdf" )
Here the link obtained

http://localhost:3000/pdfs//pdf/telecharger.php%3Fdir=JOURNAL&file=20140701.pdf
While the correct link is form the scraped site:
www.elwatan.com/pdf/telecharger.php%3Fdir=JOURNAL&file=20140701.pdf

Any hint about how to solve this issue ?
Thank you very much

Comment: Ok, I thought the `link.text` was some readable text, which could then be used to find the actual href. But somehow you seem to put the href in the link? Or is the text of the link the link itself?

Comment: Yep, the text of the link is the link itself.

Below what I get when I debug:
TEXT: Download /pdf/telecharger.php?dir=JOURNAL&file=20140701.pdf

HREF: http://localhost:3000/pdfs//pdf/telecharger.php%3Fdir=JOURNAL&file=20140701.pdf

Just in case of need, that's the part that I scrape from the external site with my xpath (//div[2]/div/p/a/@href|/img) :

<p class="vignette-pdf"><a href="/pdf/telecharger.php?dir=JOURNAL&file=20140701.pdf"><img src="/pdf/vignettes/JOURNAL/2014/20140701.jpg" /></a></p>

Many thanks

Comment: Do you understand what I am trying to do? Find some identifier so you are able to get the real link from the get request and send the real file. So in your case, I would extract the part behind the `&file=` which you can then use to build the real link. Please solve that yourself, or ask another question for this. Otherwise you could just let me do your work.